# Golang based docker image build works but not scratch based image

Tags: docker, go

I'm able to run a docker image of a web app when using `golang:1.13` base, but not when using `scratch`. The working Dockerfile is:

```
FROM golang:1.13 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o server

FROM golang:1.13
COPY --from=builder /app/server /app/server
COPY --from=builder /app/credentials/service-account.json /app/credentials/service-account.json
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/server"]
```

But when I change the final image base to `scratch` (line 6) like this:

```
FROM golang:1.13 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o server

FROM scratch # <-- CHANGED
COPY --from=builder /app/server /app/server
COPY --from=builder /app/credentials/service-account.json /app/credentials/service-account.json
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/server"]
```

I get a `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` error.

To build the docker image, I use `docker build -t myimage .`, and to run the image, I use `docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 myimage:latest`.

The app is a Go based web API that uses Gin framework, and GCP Service Account to access GCP services (the JSON file that I copy on build.)

Comment: @htaidirt - if your code uses any `cgo`, I don't think it will create a static binary. Maybe try passing the `-static` option to your `go build` command.

Comment: Hi @jakub, you're right, it looks like to be a problem related with CGO. The solution of colminator works fine. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you are not using CGO (as @jakub mentioned), try disabling CGO in your build.

So change this line in your `Dockerfile`:

```
#RUN go build -o server
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o server
```

Comment: Hi @colminator. Yes! It works. Not sure I understood what's going on. Cgo lets Go packages call C code. I don't have any C code in my code. Why is this enabled by default? And why it prevented the creation of the static binary (which is supposed to be the expected outcome of `go build`)?

Comment: It's a build optimization. Builds on your local machine will be faster with CGO enabled. It will use your native OS's DNS resolver etc. So what was happening in your problem: you were building for the `golang` docker image - and it's native libraries. Transporting that build executable to a scratch (empty) image fails, as the the (golang image) OS libraries are missing. `CGO_ENABLED=0` builds a standalone executable with no external library dependencies - perfect for `scratch`.